# C# Pass objects to ApiController in Owin host

Tags: c#, owin

I have a Windows service that does some stuff on timer ticks. Now I need to add an API endpoint to this service to do almost the same stuff, but on-demand. In my service I have two instances of helper classes:

```
LithiumUtility lu;
MarketoUtility mu;
```

To host my endpoint I use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost package. I start it with `IDisposable _server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);` as seen in all tutorials. Startup class is nothing special as well.

My endpoint is defined in the following class:

```
public class MarketoController : ApiController{}
```

So, is there a way to pass my `mu` and `lu` to `MarketoController`. I would think that it should be done through a constructor, but `MarketoController` is not referred explicitly anywhere and I am not sure how it is even created.

Comment: Even if you are hosting the API in your service, you should call it through it's endpoints. For example, by using a `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I could not find an answer on "How can I use a **concrete instance** of some class". At least without installing 10 additional packages and writing 100 lines of code.

So I went with this dirty approach:

I created this class:

```
   struct UtilityClasses
{
    public class1 c1 { get; set; }
    public class2 c2 { get; set; }

    public static UtilityClasses uc { get; set; }
    public UtilityClasses(class1 c1, class2 c2)
    {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }
}
```

Near the line that starts the server `IDisposable _server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)`, I call

```
        UtilityClasses uc = new UtilityClasses(c1, c2);
        UtilityClasses.uc = uc;
```

and from my controller, I call

```
    private class1 c1;
    private class2 c2;


    public MarketoController()
    {
        c1 = UtilityClasses.uc.c1;
        c2 = UtilityClasses.uc.c2;
    }
```

According to all I've read this is not a good idea, but it solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved using [asp.net dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Summary: calling `services.AddScoped<LithiumUtility>` within `Startup.ConfigureServices` wires up the asp.net pipeline to understand how to create instances of the constructor dependencies, so you are correct that the controller's constructor is the right place to specify these dependencies.,

Comment: So I added `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` to my Startup and added a constructor to my Controller, the one thing that remains unclear is how do I pass the existing instance of my class? These instances depend on external config strings (login credentials). So I need to pass external (to Startup) data anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I've solved using [ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) (a single nuget package) and ToConstant method.

You can see an example below :

```
appBuilder.UseNinjectMiddleware(() => {
                var kernel = new StandardKernel();
                kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(myFooInstance);
                return kernel;
            });
```